# How to detect a specific number of mentions in a message | discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want my dc bot to add a reaction to messages containing 4 or more tags (different user needs to be tagged) and add ✅ reaction to their message but I have no clue how to do so. This is what I have tried so far:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.mentions:
        await message.add_reaction("✅")
```

But it doesn't really make sense because it will add a reaction to any message containing one or more tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check for the amount of mentions, so something like this should work:

```
    if len(message.mentions) > 3:
        await message.add_reaction("✅")
```

This will already only account for unique mentions, if you mention one user multiple times this will filter it out.